# How to integrate react boilerplate into existing jquery application?

Tags: reactjs, react-boilerplate

I am trying to port a modular jquery application to react using the boilerplate. I want to move module by module.

What is the best way to integrate a boilerplate application into an existing modular jquery application?

Latest react and boilerplate. jQuery 3.1.0 with bootstrap.

I am currently just trying to get the shell html with bootstrap navigation to load. When I reference jquery and bootstrap in the index.html, the files are not copied over to the compiled application.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: I would suggest using create react app instead of react boilerplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and switched to CRA since it is simpler with no issues. However, it would be beneficial to be able to do the something similar with the boiler plate.